# Best pair of words to describe two contrasting responses to social oppression?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, personality

Suppose Bob and Jeff are both poor rural White Americans.

Bob's personality converts his tough situation into animosity toward struggling Black Americans (and related concepts such as reparations). This phenomenon, notably, was lamented by the abolitionist [Fredrick Douglass](https://msuweb.montclair.edu/%7Efurrg/spl/douglassqq.html).

Jeff, however, feels solidarity for the urban poverty many people of color face and sees their struggles as similar under the skin. Jeff seeks to form alliances between different marginalized peoples.

What is a pair of English words and/or short phrases to contrast Bob and Jeff's reactions?

Comment: Paraphrasing a recent quote I heard regarding this, in general: Most people develop empathy from enduring hardship, but some become embittered, sociopaths, or even monsters.

Comment: They could be hawk and dove.

Comment: Bigot and savior.

Comment: Conservative and progressive.

Comment: @Barmar: There isn't that strong of a correlation between political orientation and personal behavior (this may be changing). It is a "conservative" thing to use "harsh policies". And socially speaking ghosting others is a punitive and usually irreversible measure. I have only ghosted two people in my life (using gentler boundaries instead), despite actively reaching out to a large number of people. It's my last resort. But most people I met, whether conservative or liberal, ghosted others much more easily.

Comment: Ghosting is usually personal (e.g. ghosting a former boyfriend/girlfriend after a bad breakup), not based on political ideologies. But belief in progressive policies tends to correlate to feeling kinship with people. Conservative policies correspond to an "us vs them" mentality.

Comment: Resentment and sympathy? Racism and anti racism? Competition and solidarity? Hate and love? The question could be more precise about what aspect of the reaction is of interest.

Comment: @StuartF "Competition and solidarity" sounds to me like exactly the kind of thing OP is asking for!